# How to Identify the column with the max value per row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery, unpivot

I have a table that looks like the below:

```
--------------------------------
ENTITY  |  VALUE X  |  VALUE Y  
--------------------------------
AAA     |    100    |    50     
--------------------------------
BBB     |     0     |    20      
--------------------------------
CCC     |    null   |    null   
--------------------------------
DDD     |    100    |    100    
--------------------------------
```

I want to identify which of the columns (X or Y) has the largest value (in my actual data set there are five column but I'm using two here for simplicity).

In the event of both being null, I would like the result to be null.

In the event of a tie, I would like to have a set rank for tie breakers (x > y > z...)

The desired output would look like the one below

```
---------------------------------------------------
ENTITY  |  VALUE X  |  VALUE Y  |  DESIRED OUTPUT  
---------------------------------------------------
AAA     |    100    |    50     |         X        
---------------------------------------------------
BBB     |     0     |    20     |         Y          
---------------------------------------------------
CCC     |    null   |    null   |       null       
---------------------------------------------------
DDD     |    100    |    100    |         X        
---------------------------------------------------
```

I keep trying to use `MAX()` however, I think this is mainly meant for comparing rows within a column, not the opposite...

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `case` logic.  Assuming none of the values are `NULL`:

```
select t.*,
       (case greatest(x, y)
            when x then 'x'
            when y then 'y'
        end) 
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than two columns as explained in the question, then the most scalable approach uses a lateral join. The idea is to unpivot the columns to rows, filter out `null`  values, then order by descending value, and keep the top row only:

```
select t.*, x.*
from mytable t
outer apply (
    select col
    from (
        select 'X' col, t.value_x val from dual
        union all select 'Y', t.value_y from dual
    ) x
    where x.val is not null
    order by x.val desc
    fetch first 1 row only
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=24af493846ef61cd2b40e226aabb3b90)**:

```
ENTITY | VALUE_X | VALUE_Y | COL 
:----- | ------: | ------: | :---
AAA    |     100 |      50 | X   
BBB    |       0 |      20 | Y   
CCC    |    null |    null | null
DDD    |     100 |     100 | X
```